# Append multiple divs on click with same name and save its as different records in database

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to append a select box (select 1) when clicking an "add" button. Inside this select for particular ID, I need to add another select select box (say select box 2). On select of particular ID in second select box (select box 2), it should generate another person details form.

This process should repeat every time the "add" button is pressed. And I need to save each data as diff record in database.

Could anybody help me with an example?

Comment: Can you please show how you approached this problem.

Comment: I tried something like this